# Connect gnome-system-monitor to another (headless) machine

Tags: debian, gnome, monitoring, gnome-system-monitor

This might be a shot in the dark, but I am wondering if there is a way that I can connect my system monitor on my computer to my headless box.  It would be awesome to somehow use that interface display what is going on on my server, from my Desktop.

I am of course aware of tools like `top` and other web based monitors that I could use... but I think it would be cool to use Gnome's.

Comment: BTW: Happy birthday to me!  Today is my year anniversary of joining SE! :)

Comment: :)) here's an "up" for that...

Comment: [Check this out...](https://github.com/dbothwell/remote-linux-monitor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is so *awesome* on `gnome-system-monitor`? I don't know about any way to do that, but feel free to hack it. It is open source.

This application is just "desktop toy". It does not have ambitions to monitor different hosts. If you are interested in monitoring server, there are different tools that do that and do that in better way (and you might even run them on local machine with monitoring the remote on ... cockpit for example).